# SQL - Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am trying to execute this script in Oracle 11g and getting the following error, I dont know where I am missing the paranthesis or what is the mistake kindly help me figure this out.

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE User_Role ( 
  user_role_id INT  NOT NULL  , 
  Users_user_id INT  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(user_id), 
  User_Types_user_type VARCHAR(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User_Types(user_type),  
  PRIMARY KEY(user_role_id) 
)
```

Error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete `FOREIGN KEY` clause. Rewrite your `CREATE TABLE` statement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE User_Role ( 
      user_role_id         INT  NOT NULL  , 
      Users_user_id        INT  REFERENCES Users(user_id), 
      User_Types_user_type VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES User_Types(user_type),  
      PRIMARY KEY(user_role_id) 
    )
```

In this case constraint names will be generated by Oracle. If you want to give them more meaningful names you could write your `create table` statement as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE User_Role1 ( 
      user_role_id         INT  NOT NULL  , 
      Users_user_id        INT  , 
      User_Types_user_type VARCHAR(20) ,  
      constraint PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY(user_role_id), 
      constraint FK_Table_1 foreign key(Users_user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id),
      constraint FK_Table_2 foreign key(User_Types_user_type) REFERENCES User_Types(user_type)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the columns first and then add the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint in the very same manner as you are adding `PRIMARY KEY` constraint as below:

```
    CREATE TABLE User_Role ( 
       user_role_id INT  NOT NULL  , 
       Users_user_id INT, 
       User_Types_user_type VARCHAR(20),
       FOREIGN KEY (Users_user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id),
       FOREIGN KEY (User_Types_user_type) REFERENCES User_Types(user_type), 
       PRIMARY KEY(user_role_id) 
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the size of int and recompile

Example :-

```
integer (20) not null
integer not null
User_Types_user_type VARCHAR(20),
User_Types_user_type VARCHAR,
```

Comment: There is no `integer(20)` in the example. And `VARCHAR` without a size is invalid in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* specify foreign keys inline, you just need to remove the `foreign key` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE User_Role 
(
  user_role_id           INT NOT NULL  , 
  Users_user_id          INT         REFERENCES Users, 
  User_Types_user_type   VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES User_Types,  
  PRIMARY KEY(user_role_id) 
);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ca9f/1

Listing the primary key columns in the "references" part is optional. If you prefer, you can also write `REFERENCES Users(user_id)`

This format also has the disadvantage that the constraint names will be generated by Oracle (with a meaningless name). In order to be able to properly specify a constraint name for the foreign key, you need to use the syntax in the accepted answer.